# how to read ending URL numbers as a value?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a survey page that will reference an invoice number. I'm trying to make the URL clean so that there are no question marks or equal sign. For example:

> http://www.MyWebsite.com/survey/832551

Where 832551 is the invoice ID in reference. I am trying to avoid `?invoice_ID=832551`.

How can I get a php page to read that and make it a variable value?

php 4.0.8

Comment: using your .htaccess file will sort this out http://www.edinteractive.co.uk/article/?id=48

Comment: What would htaccess file need to contain?

Comment: The link will tell you how to do that. Also PHP 4.0.8 is very outdated

Comment: THanks. I'll ask system admin to upgrade php. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Make an variable with url

```
//You get all the url in array
$var = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
//Explode it in array, with slash '/'
$var_array = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
//Get the last element of array, which will be the invoice_id
$invoice_id = array_pop($var_array);
```

But if you use some of php framework this is how you get controller attribute by default, 
I suggest you to use some php framework with MVC structure.

Comment: Where should he put that code into? index.php? But the server would not load it, with a request like "http://www.MyWebsite.com/survey/832551"...

Comment: You're welcome, but maybe there's is better way to do this, you can upvote my answer!:)

Answer (score 1):

It is what we call URL rewriting.

You can find a good example here

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/